# Why are the inverses of triangular matrices always triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The inverse of an (invertible) upper triangular matrix is always upper triangular and the inverse of an (invertible) lower triangular matrix is always lower triangular. Why?

I don't have any work to show and this isn't homework.

Comment: see if http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245871/proving-the-inverse-if-any-of-a-lower-triangular-matrix-is-lower-triangular helps

Comment: @ChristopherErnst I don't see how that comment helps the asker.

Comment: True...  Removed.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/inverse-of-a-triangular-matrix-both-upper-lower-is-triangular?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

A *flagged vector space* of dimension $n$ is a vector space $V$ equipped with a filtration $$0\subseteq V_1 \subseteq \dots \subseteq V_n,$$ where the dimension increases by $1$ at each step. A morphism $V \to W$ of flagged vector spaces of the same dimension is a linear transformation which respects the flags.

A triangular matrix is nothing but an endomorphism of the flagged vector space

$$0\subseteq \mathbf F^1 \subseteq \dots  \subseteq \mathbf F^n.$$

It is immediate that among these, the isomorphisms correspond to invertible triangular matrices, which therefore form a group under matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the inverse of $A$ by row reduction in the extended matrix $(A|I)$. You should just trace what is happening to the identity matrix $I$ on the right while doing the row reduction process.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints and proofs can be found on the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245871/proving-the-inverse-if-any-of-a-lower-triangular-matrix-is-lower-triangular) in the comments above.

Another simple proof can be made by induction. It is clear that the statement is true for $n=1$. Assume that it is true as well for matrices of dimension $n-1$ and consider an $n\times n$ upper triangular and nonsingular matrix $U$ in the block form
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}\nu & u^* \\ 0 & \tilde{U}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\tilde{U}$ is $(n-1)\times (n-1)$. Since $U$ is assumed to be nonsingular and so $\nu\neq 0$ and $\tilde{U}$ is nonsingular. Since the statement is true for $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices, $\tilde{U}^{-1}$ is upper triangular. Now let
$$
U^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&b^*\\c&D\end{bmatrix}
$$
be the partitioning of $U^{-1}$ conforming to the partitioning of $U$. Then $UU^{-1}=I$ is equivalent to
$$
\alpha\nu+u^*c=1, \quad
\nu b+D^*u=0, \quad
\tilde{U}c=0, \quad
\tilde{U}D=I.
$$
The last two equations imply that $D=\tilde{U}^{-1}$ and $c=0$, which already implies that $U^{-1}$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are assuming that $A$ is invertible we know that for any linear independent set of vectors $x_k$ $\>(1\leq k\leq r)$ the vectors $Ax_k$ are again linearly independent.

If the matrix of $A$ with respect to the basis $(e_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ is upper triangular then for each $r\in[n]$ one has
$$A\bigl(\langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle\bigr)\subset \langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle\ ,$$
and on account of the preliminary remark we even can say that
$$A\bigl(\langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle\bigr) = \langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle\ .$$
Applying $A^{-1}$ on both sides of the last equation gives
$$\langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle =A^{-1}\bigl( \langle e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_r\rangle\bigr)\qquad(1\leq r\leq n)\ ,$$
and this says that the matrix of $A^{-1}$ with respect to the basis $(e_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ is upper triangular.