# simple showing inverse of matrix also upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm trying to show that A be a $ 3 x 3 $ upper triangular matrix with $det \ne 0 $. Show by explicit computation that $A^{-1}$ is also upper triangular. Simple showing is enough for me.

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}a & \color{blue}b & \color{blue}c \\0 & \color{blue}d & \color{blue}e \\ 0 & 0 &\color{blue}f\end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone explain and show it?

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
a&b&c\\%
0&d&e\\%
0&0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
$$
$$
x11=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
d&e\\%
0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=df, x12=-\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
0&e\\%
0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=0, x13=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
0&d\\%
0&0\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=0
$$
$$
x21=-\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
b&c\\%
0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=-bf, X22=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
a&c\\%
0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=af, X23=-\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
a&b\\%
0&0\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=0
$$
$$
x31=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
b&c\\%
d&e\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=bc-cd, x32=-\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
a&c\\%
0&e\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=ac, x31=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
a&b\\%
0&d\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=ad
$$
$$
adjoint A = \left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
df&0&0\\%
-bf&af&0\\%
bc-cd&-ac&ad\\%
\end{array}\right)%
$$
$$
det A = a\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
d&e\\%
0&f\\%
\end{array}\right)%
=adf
$$
$$
Inverse-A =1/adf  \left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
df&0&0\\%
-bf&af&0\\%
bc-cd&-ac&ad\\%
\end{array}\right)%
$$
It came out lower triangular matrix. Is there any way to make it upper triangular matrix?

Comment: Why did you remove the context? We can't help you very well if you don't share your thoughts and efforts.

Comment: See the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%5B%5Ba%2Cb%2Cc%5D%2C%5B0%2Cd%2Ce%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2Cf%5D%5D) given by WA.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1058322/28900) and [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/245871/28900).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of proceeding in terms of adjoints, it would be a great deal easier to proceed as follows.

First of all, note that each of $a,c,f$ is nonzero. Next, consider the augmented matrix $[A\mid I_3],$ where $I_3$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix. Perform row operations on the augmented matrix until it is in the form $[I_3\mid B].$ The matrix $B$ is the inverse of $A,$ which you can (and should) verify by showing that $AB=I_3.$

Answer (score 1):

Your work is fine but you forgot to transpose the adjoint!

The inverse is essentially given by the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), which is the *transpose* of the cofactor matrix.