# What does non-singularity have to do with lower triangular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a lower triangular matrix of order $n$. I am asked to verify the following assertion:

If $ A $ is nonsingular, then $ A^k $ is lower triangular for all integers k.

Comment: Well, if you want to define $A^k$ for $k<0$ you need $A$ to be non-singular...

Comment: Can you see why positive powers $A^k$ must be lower triangular? Can you prove that the inverse must be lower triangular? Once you've shown these two things, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be lower triangular.

---

Case 1: $k=0$

I think we are supposed to have

$A^0 = I$

while $A^0 = AA^{-1}$

So we need invertibility.

---

Case 2: $k < 0$

Obviously we need invertibility.

As to why $A^k$ is still lower triangular, note that

1. $$A^k = (A^{-1})^{-k}$$
2. [The inverse of a lower triangular matrix is a lower triangular matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245871/proving-the-inverse-if-any-of-a-lower-triangular-matrix-is-lower-triangular) Hence $A^{-1}$ is a lower triangular matrix.
3. [The finite product of lower triangular matrices is a lower triangular matrix.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Triangular_Matrices)

Hence $\underbrace{A^{-1}A^{-1} \cdots A^{-1}}_{k \ times}$ is a lower triangular matrix.

---

Case 3: $k > 0$

Invertibility is not needed here. Consider

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

or even

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

P.S. [Some properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)

$$\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii} \ \text{if A is triangular}$$

$$\det(A^2) = (\det(A))^2$$

$$\det(A^{-1}) = (\det(A))^{-1}$$